# JS - click() не хочет работать

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему метод .click() не работает, как реальный клик ?

Пишу в хроме в консоле простой код:

```
{let my_let = document.getElementsByClassName("Textinput-Control")[0]; my_let.click();}
```

Это поле ввода логина, но самого клика не происходит, потому что, если сделать реальный клик, то выпадает список, в котром хром предлагает выбрать сохраненные логины, а .click() - получается не эмулирует клик мыши ?

Comment: Можете попробовать метод .focus()

Comment: @HTO HOT, пробовал и .focus() и .focus() и потом .click() - не срабатывает, там что то видимо сложное.

Answer (score 0):

Нет функции `.click()`, вы должны использовать `.onclick`

`button.onclick = function(){}`

Comment: Как нет - если я ее использую.

Comment: Есть!
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click